# onKeyReleased does not work when a character is typed

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to disable the button when the text fields are empty.
I have created two fields with the onKeyReleased property

Sorry i sent it unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `btn.disableProperty().bind(field.textProperty().isEmpty())` should work.

In the future please add a compilable skeleton and what you have tried so far to your question. That makes it way easier to help.

And welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: Or `btn.disableProperty().bind(field.textProperty().isEmpty())`.

Comment: @Slaw That is way shorter and less convoluted! I will add that to my answer if you don't mind?

Comment: I don't mind at all. Here's a [link to the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/StringExpression.html#isEmpty()) if you want to include that as well. And [another link](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#isEmpty(javafx.beans.value.ObservableStringValue)) showing an alternative (i.e. `Bindings#isEmpty(ObservableStringValue)`).

Comment: Thank you, it works. so the first question is always :)